# How to deal with inappropriate behaviour from a moderator?

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

Take a second to read these comments by Napoleon Wilson:
[image]
[image]

I would have added more examples of his condescending behavior but he simply removed his comments that were even more condescending (and my responses to them). That is why I had to take a screenshot this time. It is ironic that he demonstrates this kind of behavior in the question entitled [How can we punish a mod?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/how-can-we-punish-a-mod). This is how our discussion has been going: I asked a question, he talks down to me, I respond, he removes the evidence of his inappropriate behavior.

I am fine with my questions being removed: moderation keeps the site content on the level. But how do we moderate the moderators? I do not wish to be talked down to. How do I deal with the mod's inappropriate behavior? Who do I complain to? How do I retrieve the evidence of his behavior if he keeps removing it?

Answer (score 11):

I will certainly not spend any time challenging your specific accusations in any way (and would advise everyone else to do the same). Rather, to concentrate on the actual question buried under this rant, this has been [asked on Meta Stack Exchange before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/162011). To summarize the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28869/162011) there:

> If you have a dispute with a diamond moderator your options are:
>
> - Send a message to the Stack Exchange team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page with your complaint and links to the questions/answers.
> - Flag for moderator attention and request a second moderator to have a look.

So if you really see a problem with a moderator's behaviour, you can [contact SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/contact). This will go directly to the CMs, i.e. the Stack Exchange employees "moderating the moderators", without getting relayed *directly* to the site moderators (it might of course in the process of working on the mentioned problems, though). These people can also see any deleted posts and comments you might need to help "build a case" against said moderator.

Comment: It has been over a month since I have contacted SE via https://movies.stackexchange.com/contact and I have not received any response whatsoever so I have unmarked you answer as the answer. Apparently SE does not care about the feedback I have provided.

Comment: Well, it's not like you're entitled a response. Maybe they simply didn't agree with your assessment or deemed the responses you already got from the community and the moderators sufficient. You're of course free to unaccept the answer, it's however still the proper way to go on this. But if the top-level instances don't agree with you, you're pretty much out of support, I'm afraid.